# Get all DB objects with same name but different case in SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Current collation of database: Latin1_General_BIN
I have objects like

```
AA - store proc
Aa - View
AB - table
Ab - trigger
CC - Table
DD - table
```

Can I get the list of object and type where objects are in same name but different case.

list I am looking for

```
  AA - store proc Aa - View
  AB - table Ab - trigger
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT o.name collate latin1_general_ci_ai,o.type_desc 
FROM sys.objects o
group by o.name collate latin1_general_ci_ai,o.type_desc
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: SELECT o.name collate latin1_general_ci_ai
FROM sys.objects o
group by o.name collate latin1_general_ci_ai
having count(*)>1